# Why dropdown autoload is not working in iOS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add autoload in my website but this code is not working in iOS browsers, Chrome or Safari. In other OS is working perfectly, including android devices.
This code I got from https://codepen.io/matt-west/pen/jKnzG.

```
<div id="page-wrapper">
  <h1>Datalist Element Demo</h1>

  <label for="default">Pick a programming language</label>
  <input type="text" id="default" list="languages" placeholder="e.g. JavaScript">

  <datalist id="languages">
    <option value="HTML">
    <option value="CSS">
    <option value="JavaScript">
    <option value="Java">
    <option value="Ruby">
    <option value="PHP">
    <option value="Go">
    <option value="Erlang">
    <option value="Python">
    <option value="C">
    <option value="C#">
    <option value="C++">
  </datalist>


  <label for="ajax">Pick an HTML Element (options loaded using AJAX)</label>
  <input type="text" id="ajax" list="json-datalist" placeholder="e.g. datalist">
  <datalist id="json-datalist"></datalist>


</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Datalists are not supported in iOS or Safari. It was working in Chrome for me though, so you might be on an older version of Chrome (or Chrome is on iOS maybe isn't supported if that's what you tried)

https://caniuse.com/#feat=datalist